# What does E x~y notation mean in functions?

Tags: functions, expected-value, entropy, scientific-notation

In some articles there is a notation like E x~y , does this "E" mean expected value(mean) or it is referring to something else?

[image: E x~y example]

for example in this formula, how can I read the first part (E X~Pg) where X is input sentence and Pg is the probability of being fake text

thanks in advance

Comment: $\mathbb{E}_{X\sim Y} Z$ means: the expectation of the expression $Z$ when $X$ is a random variable with distribution $Y$.

Comment: thanks a lot 